# Returning blank string when having quotation (")

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I`m trying to find values that contains quotation marks ("). But when they returns, it comes with a empty string. This is happening with this piece code:

```
query = Model.where(position: position + 1).in_area(area).of_type(area_type).order('id DESC').includes(:recipe, :category)
query = query.where(category_id: ((category)? category : nil))
this_area << query.first
```

It is expected to return values like: 'My name is "Jean Paul"'
But it returns only a empty string.
I`m using ruby on rails with mysql2 gem.

I don`t want to find specific values with quotation, but when they come with quotation, it returns empty.

Comment: Probably you try to concatenate string with NULL

Comment: But I m not concatenating values, I m just searching for a value and it retuns empty when having " (quotation) on database.

Comment: The quotation is on database, I do not want to find specific values with quotations. I am making queries like "SELECT * FROM table_name"

Comment: When you say "it returns an empty string", what do you mean?  I'd expect this to return an instance of your Model class, or `nil`.

Comment: On `query.first` it returns a instance of a model, but it has a attribute that is string, and this string returns empty if the value comes with quotes.